# R function for automated combining vectors and storing them as variables

Tags: r, function, loops

I have a vector of vectors, say

```
c(a,b,c)
```

where a, b, c are previously-stored vectors with equal length. I want to create a function in R that automatically combines all elements in this vector and store them as variables in a product vector (vector multiplication), or more explicitly:

```
function(c(a,b,c))= c(ab,ac,bc,abc)
```

How should I do this? Thanks

Comment: Warning a vector of vector is a vector : `c(1:2, 1:3)` is `[1] 1 2 1 2 3`

Comment: `fun <- function(...) c(...)` perhaps? Usage: `fun(a, b, c)`.

Comment: If `a` and `b` are vectors, what would `ab` be? `c(a, b)` ? Or since you also mention *product* vector `a * b`?

Comment: What is a "product vector"? A vector of products? If yes, are `a`, `b` and `c` always of equal length?

Comment: Yes, I mean the product vector from matrix multiplication. and yes, a, b, c are always equal length

Comment: Umm, matrix multiplication? Are you sure that you want matrix multiplication and not element-wise multiplication?

Comment: This question would be much clearer if you gave an explicit example. What output do you expect for the input `a = 1:3, b = 4:6, c = 11:13`? When you write `ab` and say "product vector", do you mean `a*b`, `t(a) %*% b`, `a %*% t(b)`, `prod(a, b)`.... or something else?

Comment: And, in the output, do you want to be able to distinguish between, say, `ac` and `bc` through labels or any other way? Or is the presence in the vector enough? Does it need to generalize to different numbers of inputs? Are there always three vectors input? If not, what happens with 2 or 4 or more?

Comment: I mean the product operation I'm looking for in this specific instance is a*b, but I looking for a general idea to write a loop that select elements from a list. Similar with the number of vector of inputs. I'm using an example of 3 tuples since I don't want to list out all possible combination from 4 tuple :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `combn` and some `lapply` and `Reduce` loops:

```
foo <- function(...) {
  args <- list(...)
  res <- lapply(seq_along(args)[-1], function(i)
    lapply(combn(list(a, b, c), i, simplify = FALSE), 
           function(x) Reduce(`*`, x))
  )
  unlist(res, FALSE)
}

a <- 1:3
b <- 4:6
c <- 7:9
foo(a, b, c)
#[[1]]
#[1]  4 10 18
#
#[[2]]
#[1]  7 16 27
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 28 40 54
#
#[[4]]
#[1]  28  80 162
```

However, instead of `c(a, b, c)` you need to use `list(a, b, c)` or `...` as I show. If you use `c(a, b, c)` the information which value belonged to which original vector is lost.

Comment: This is brilliant. I didn't know I could use seq_along to index the list of vectors. Thanks